# Splunk sendemail fails [Errno 99] with mailserver smtp.gmail.com

Tags: smtp, splunk, mail-server

From `/opt/splunk/var/log/splunk/python.log`:

```
2018-11-12 14:29:08,776 +0000 ERROR    sendemail:137 - Sending email. subject="Splunk Alert: Errors in develop", results_link="https://localhost:8000/app/search/@go?sid=rt_scheduler__admin__search__RMD58e26482826eced90_at_1542024571_26.426", recipients="[u'my_email@gmail.com']", server="localhost"
2018-11-12 14:29:08,776 +0000 ERROR    sendemail:458 - [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address while sending mail to: my_email@gmail.com
```

My `/opt/splunk/etc/system/local/alert_actions.conf`:

```
 [email]
 auth_password = XXX
 auth_username = my_email@gmail.com
 hostname = localhost
 mailserver = smtp.gmail.com:465
 pdf.header_left = none
 pdf.header_right = none
 use_ssl = 1
```

I also tried `smtp.gmail.com:587` with `use_ssl = 0 use_tls = 1`, got same error in both cases.

However, when trying to send mail directly from search, it works as expected:

```
... | sendemail to="my_email@gmail.com" format=raw sendresults=1 footer="Sent from Splunk." from="SplunkAlerts" subject="Splunk Alert" message="The following Splunk Alert has been fired:"
```

what configuration am I missing? errno 99 is EADDRNOTAVAIL , not clear what is not available, is it the `server="localhost"` in the error log? where should I set it?

Answer (score 1):

In your config, you need to use `server=`, not `mailserver`.

https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/7.2.0/SearchReference/Sendemail

Please note that often Gmail will be finicky about trying to send email through it this way, and I tend to avoid it if possible. Do you have a local mail server configured?

Comment: the config was generated by splunk web.. anyway when editing it manually and adding also `server = smtp.gmail.com:465`, its still showing `localhost` in the error log

Comment: See the solution posted here, https://answers.splunk.com/answers/548703/why-are-mailserver-settings-in-alert-actionsconf-n.html

Comment: I don't have any local `savedsearches.conf`, nor would I would to define a `[savedsearch-name]` in config per alert, unless there was some automatic generation

Answer (score 0):

For the meantime I'm using the following script as a workaround:

```
temp="/tmp/results_$(date -u +%s).csv"
gunzip < $8 > $temp
printf "$1 alarming logs were found by $4\n$6" | \
  SMTP_URL='smtps://my_email%40gmail.com:password@smtp.gmail.com' mutt \
  -F /dev/null \
  -e 'set from="Splunk <my_email@gmail.com>"' \
  -e 'set smtp_url=$SMTP_URL' \
  -s "Splunk: $4" \
  -a $temp --  \
  target@gmail.com
rm -rf $temp
```

at `$SPLUNK_HOME/bin/scripts/sendmail.sh`

Comment: actually a better workaround was to edit the contents of `/opt/splunk/etc/apps/search/bin/sendemail.py`, not sure what in configuration is not read correctly